# Linux: what's the source of keypress event with keycode 255?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, keyboard-events

It's a laptop running Gentoo Linux, amd64. The problem is that something automatically generates keypress events of the following type(captured using `xev` utility):

```
KeyPress event, serial 49, synthetic NO, window 0x3e00001,
root 0xf5, subw 0x0, time 1465436, (1196,-210), root:(1198,406),
state 0x10, keycode 255 (keysym 0x0, NoSymbol), same_screen YES,
XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
XFilterEvent returns: False
```

This particularly causes annoying problem in a terminal window with auto-scroll configured to run on a keypress - it scrolls down to the command prompt after some 15 seconds.

I want to locate the source of this event, then disable it.

Kernel configuration: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4T1g89tYDs0UkhSX1ZmMW5ZeXc/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Use **`xinput list`** to determine the input devices that are present on your system.
>
> Next, use **`xinput test`** or **`xinput test-xi2`** to monitor individual events from any input device.

Checkout this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/129171/129246) for details.

Comment: I've found that it was "Virtual core XTEST keyboard id=5". Now I'll search for a way to disable it. By the way, `sudo xinput --disable 5` fails: `BadAccess (attempt to access private resource denied)`.

Comment: @ruslan hmmm... can you try `sudo xinput set-prop 5 "Device Enabled" 0` as described [**here**](http://askubuntu.com/a/67724).

Comment: just the same BadAccess error. I'd be satisfied with disabling just `keycode 255`

Comment: `sudo xinput float 5` should do it then. Before trying it though, *do NOTE the `master#` and procedure to enable it back again as described [**here**](http://askubuntu.com/a/178741).*

Comment: yen, I tried this, too: `XI_BadDevice (invalid Device parameter)`

Comment: Fixed by disabling X server's XTEST extension: `X -tst`. Thanks